# Angular multiple input search request with http request

Tags: angular, http

I'm learning how to use Angular with an API and I have a search box where I can search for a data, now I want to make multiple searches as in if I make a search and get the result and clear and type different keyword I still get a result but I don't seem to get any after.

app.component.html

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder=""  [(ngModel)]="inputKeyword" name="search" />
```

app.component.ts

```
searchData() { 
 this.results = this.googleService.getGoogle(this.inputKeyword)
  .subscribe(x =>{
    this.googleData = x.items;
    console.log('googleData', this.googleData);
      }, error => {
     console.log("error here",error)
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.. Assuming latest version(s) of Angular.
Here is a stackbliz example: https://angular-j19wsj.stackblitz.io

in the app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
Enter search value:  
<input type="text" name="search" (keyup)="search($event)">
<br>

<ng-container *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data">

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let x of data">{{x}}</li>
  </ul>

</ng-container>
```

Then in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  searchValue$ = new Subject<string>();
  data$: Observable<string[]>;

  testData = [
    'mike',
    'john',
    'john doe',
    'susan',
    'susie'
  ]

  constructor(){

    this.searchValue$.pipe(
      switchMap(sv=>{
        //reeturn apiservice.get(searchvalue);
        console.log('sv is' ,sv)
        return of(this.testData.filter(x=>x.startsWith(sv)));
      })
    ).subscribe(result=>{
      this.data$ = of(result);
    })
  }

  search(e:KeyboardEvent){
    this.searchValue$.next(e.target.value);
  }
}
```

And then you can throw in some debounce to prevent from being called too much

Comment: that great with your feedback, I kinda a bit confused with your approach, do you mind explaining a bit because I'm getting some errors as I implemented.

Comment: I updated the example...and created a stackblitz example  https://angular-j19wsj.stackblitz.io

Comment: That's great, very similar to what I wanted but I'm still sorting out to work in my situation.